# Sending multiple php strings in Twilio Body

Tags: twilio

Friends I'm trying to pass a number of strings from a post such as $name $phonenumber, etc

```
$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
$client->messages->create(
// Where to send a text message (your cell phone?)
'+16477458535',
array(
'from' => $twilio_number,
'body' => $message
)
```

but can't seem to concatenate like this:

```
'body' => $message, $name, phone
```

etc...
???

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are a couple of ways to build a string out of multiple variables like that.

You can use [the `.` operator, which directly concatenates strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), for example:

```php
'body' => $message . $name . $phone
```

Though this will push all the strings together, so if the `$message` was "hello", the `$name` was "Phil" and the `$phone` was "+012345" it would come out as "helloPhil+012345". You can add spaces into the concatenation to get over that:

```php
'body' => $message . " " . $name . " " . $phone
```

Alternatively, you can [interpolate the variables into a string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), like so:

```php
'body' => "${message} ${name} ${phone}"
```